# Set global variable between multithreaded netlogo experiment runs

Tags: netlogo

I have a netlogo simulation that runs on a graph. It takes some time to process this graph from a shapefile. I would like to process it once, set it as a global variable, and have each simulation use that.

I tried setting some marker variable in my setup, and if it wasn't initialized, process the graph, but the graph is processed every time.
I think because the multithreaded simulation doesn't share a global variable space.

I'm running through the `netlogo-headless.sh` script, but I also tried through the GUI when the global variables were initialized, but I assume that the simulation runner ignores the current state.

This same issue was also mentioned here: http://netlogo-users.18673.x6.nabble.com/Behavior-space-and-random-numbers-td4861070.html but no solution.

Is there any way to do this?

My only thought at this point is maybe write out the processed graph in some way it's faster to read, but that's a poor workaround.

Comment: how about using `export-world` and `import-world`?

Comment: I don't understand why you think it's a poor workaround to save and load the network. Are you doing anything else with that shapefile? I suspect not, because otherwise you would need to import the shapefile regardless of whether you need to generate the network. If you aren't doing anything else with the shapefile and it's only purpose is to justify your network, then the network is the object of interest and saving it is sensible. Have a look at the network extension for load and save primitives.

Comment: @JenB You're right, I was thinking about it wrong. Thank you for the pointer to the network extension, looks like what I need.

Comment: @SethTisue Thank you, but that exports everything, when I only care about a few things, so I think the network extension is the right path for me.